# queue container with map type

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, queue

I am trying to write a blackjack game using the STL. It needs to contain a few different containers which include `std::map` and `std::queue`. I am trying to do the following:

```
map<string, int> cards = {{"1H", 1}, {"2H", 2}};
queue<cards> deck;
```

However, I am getting errors one of which states the template argument is invalid for the queue declaration. How do I insert the `map` container into the `queue` container? I need to do this with a `list` container as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
map<string, int> cards = {{"1H", 1}, {"2H", 2}};
queue<map<string, int>> deck;
```

or to make it more readable:

```
using CardMap = std::map<string, int>;
CardMap cards = {{"1H", 1}, {"2H", 2}};
std::queue<CardMap> deck;
```

Comment: So I will need to insert the contents of the map into the queue manually?

Comment: @Ritchie: Your requirement is to insert the complete `map` in `queue` and not contents of `map` into `queue`. So once you correct the declaration of your queue, you can insert the complete `map` in `queue` in one go by using `queue::push()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the type of the object inside `< >` but you had mentioned the object directly instead of its type.

```
map<string, int> cards = {{"1H", 1}, {"2H", 2}};
queue<cards> deck; //Wrong
```

`cards` is of type `map<string, int>` so you have put this type inside `< >`.

```
queue<map<string, int>> deck; //right
```